# create new column and collect results from many rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe of matches results with a column of goals time:

```
date    match     goals_time
05-09   match_1   5
05-09   match_1   20
05-09   match_1   80
05-09   match_2   2
05-09   match_3   25
05-09   match_3   90
05-09   match_4   60
```

I want to make each match in one row and collect specific goals times in only one column:
So the result like that:

```
date    match     goals_time
05-09   match_1   5, 20, 80
05-09   match_2   2
05-09   match_3   25, 90
05-09   match_4   60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cast the column to `str` then `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df["goals_time"] = df["goals_time"].astype(str)

print (df.groupby(["date", "match"], as_index=False)["goals_time"].agg(", ".join))

    date    match goals_time
0  05-09  match_1  5, 20, 80
1  05-09  match_2          2
2  05-09  match_3     25, 90
3  05-09  match_4         60
```

Answer (score 1):

Just group by and make the `goals_time` a list:

```py
df.groupby(['date','match'])['goals_time'].apply(list)
date   match  
05-09  match_1    [5, 20, 80]
       match_2            [2]
       match_3       [25, 90]
       match_5           [60]
Name: goals_time, dtype: object
```